# Segmentation fault after input or file opening

Tags: c, file, file-io, segmentation-fault

I have to make a program that reads two files and compare them. But I got stuck in this part: I send the file pointers to a function that collects from the keyboard the name of the files and open them. It happens successfully, then something ruin it!

The error occurs **after it reads the name of the second file** or **after it opens it** somewhere. I tried to print something from file 2 inside the function that opens it and it worked. Two different problems occur: **Segmentation fault** or **nothing happens, the cursor of the terminal keeps blinking and I need to `ctrl+c` to stop running it**.

This is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>

#define TAM_PALAVRA 46 // Maior palavra do português possui 46 letras
#define TAM_ARQUIVO 50

/* *** Funções *** */
void apresentacao();
int abrirArquivos(FILE *arquivo1, FILE *arquivo2);
void fecharArquivos(FILE *arquivo1, FILE *arquivo2);

/* *** main *** */
/* Corpo do programa */
int main() {
    /* Variáveis */
    FILE *arquivo1;
    FILE *arquivo2;
    int flag = 0; // Variável de controle - 1 para arquivos inexistentes e 0 para arquivos abertos com sucesso

    /* Função para que o programa aceite caracteres da língua portuguesa */
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    /* Looping para garantir a correta abertura do programa */
    do {
        apresentacao();
        if(flag == 1) {
            printf("\tO ARQUIVO DIGITADO NÃO EXISTE. TENTE NOVAMENTE.\n\n");
        }
        flag = abrirArquivos(arquivo1, arquivo2); // Abrindo os arquivos necessários
    } while(flag);

    /* Liberando a memória */
    fecharArquivos(arquivo1, arquivo2);

    return 0;
}

/* *** apresentacao *** */
/* Explica para o usuário o que o programa faz */
void apresentacao() {
    system("clear");
    printf("\n\n\tProjeto 02 - Estruturas de Dados - Turma C");
    printf("\n\tUnB - Universidade de Brasília");
    printf("\n\tAluno: Sérgio de Castilho Mafra");
    printf("\n\tMatrícula: 08/40769");
    printf("\n\n\tCOMPARADOR DE TEXTOS");
    printf("\n\n\t\tEste programa comparará dois textos fornecidos por você, usuário,\n\te imprimirá na tela um valor que representa quão parecidos os textos são.\n\tAcima de 50%%, os textos serão considerados plágio.\n\n");
}

/* *** abrirArquivos *** */
/* Coleta do usuário os nomes dos arquivos e os abre */
int abrirArquivos(FILE *arquivo1, FILE *arquivo2) {
    char arq1[TAM_ARQUIVO+1], arq2[TAM_ARQUIVO+1];

    /* Coletando o nome dos arquivos e verificando a existência dos mesmos */
    // Arquivo 1
    printf("\tDigite o nome do primeiro arquivo: ");
    fgets(arq1, TAM_ARQUIVO, stdin);
    arq1[strlen(arq1)-1] = '\0';

    if((arquivo1 = fopen(arq1, "r")) == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }

    // Arquivo 2
    printf("\tAgora, digite o nome do segundo: ");
    fgets(arq2, TAM_ARQUIVO, stdin);
    arq2[strlen(arq2)-1] = '\0';

    if((arquivo2 = fopen(arq2, "r")) == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }

    char w[200];
    printf("\n\n\t\t%s\n\n", fgets(w, 199, arquivo2));

    // Flag 0, se os arquivos forem abertos com sucesso
    return 0;
}

void fecharArquivos(FILE *arquivo1, FILE *arquivo2) {
    fclose(arquivo1);
    fclose(arquivo2);
}
```

Comment: `fecharArquivos(arquivo1, arquivo2);` using uninitialized variables.

Comment: why should you, no matter what your nationality is, *always* write *all* of your code in English?  Because one day you might show it to the whole world out there asking for help.  Like now.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I thought of it, but I initialize them inside the function before using it the first time.

Comment: @MikeNakis My professor asked to comment the code. So it must be in Portuguese.

Comment: You can not change the caller variable in a function without using a pointer to itself.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thanks, it solved my problem!

Comment: First of all, code is one thing, comments are another.  You can write your code in English and your comments in Portugese.  But just because you have to write comments it does not mean they need to be in Portugese.  The world-wide convention is both code in English, and comments in English.

Comment: @MikeNakis ok, but this is not a code for the public. Only a project for University. So it has to be comprehensible to everyone who reads it. Some of my friends don' t speak English. It helps their comprehension. My projects on git are all in English.

Comment: "it has to be comprehensible to everyone who reads it" - Apparently not *everyone*, like the english-only readers on this site. No matter. problem solved. good on that.

Comment: @WhozCraig Reads at my University, man. The context of a phrase makes part of the global comprehension.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY hey, can you answer the question, so I can mark my question as answered by you??

Comment: This is a common mistake. I think it is probably a duplicate question, but I have not searched.